# Don't understand reason for Import error: cannot import name 'Serial' from 'serial'

Tags: python, pyserial

So as the title suggests, I am getting an error when using the `pyserial` module.

I am using the following code

```
from serial import Serial
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.port = 'COM3'
```

and am getting the following error when I run the code:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Serial' from 'serial' 
(C:\Users\OPlim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\serial\__init__.py)
```

My file is called `EASGLE_test.py`  so I know it's not trying to `import` itself, but I have no clue as to what is going wrong.

Comment: Please include the full backtrace (that includes the line in your code causing the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are importing Serial from serial

```
from serial import Serial
ser = serial.Serial()
```

change the code to:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial()
```

Comment: will try that just now

Comment: nope. got the same error as the other one 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OPlim\Desktop\EAGLE test.py", line 2, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial()
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'

Comment: Try "pip install --force-reinstall pyserial"

Comment: That's fixed the issue. thank you for your help

Comment: No worries. You may want to check the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.port = 'COM3'
```

If it's not in your cmd run: `pip install pyserial`

[Here](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports) a quick look to doc examples

Comment: I get this 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OPlim\Desktop\EAGLE test.py", line 2, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial()
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'

Comment: I have also tried pip install pyserial but I keep getting the already satisfied message

Comment: Try a ``pip install --upgrade pip``, then uninstall serial and reinstall it

Answer (score 0):

update to python 3.9
run pip install pyserial again.

Comment: Oh is that why its not working? I have been using 3.7